# My answer is shown as up-voted from me

Tags: support, answers, up-votes

I was looking at [Will anybody help me gauge the quality of my question?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/545) and I noticed that [my answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/558/199) is shown me as up-voted from me.

[image: screenshot]

How is that possible? Even in the case my account were merged with another account on *Drupal Answers* my answer would not be shown as up-voted from me.

What happened in this case?

Something similar happened me also on this very site: A question page shown as up-voted from me an answer I didn't up-vote. When I tried clicking on the up-voting button, I was even shown a dialog box saying my vote was locked.

[image: screenshot]

The question I up-voted was the other one, though. After I refreshed the page, the up-voted answers were correctly shown.

[image: screenshot]

Comparing the two screenshot, I see the score for one answer doesn't change, which I guess it means my vote was already counted, but the answer was not shown as up-voted from me.

Comment: Didn't you sign the moderator agreement?  You're not supposed to tell everyone that we can vote for our own answers!

Comment: @BilltheLizard Whoops… I was not wearing my eyeglasses when I signed it. Now I am curious: What did the part I read as "we will send you a gift for your birthday, for the next 10 years" really say?

Comment: You don't get the gifts?  I wonder where they're sending them...  ;)

Comment: If you don't mind, could you share what it says at http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/545/votes? (This indicates the votes/favourites you've cast on that question and its answers.)

Comment: @jeremybanks It says `[{"PostId":545,"VoteTypeId":3},{"PostId":546,"VoteTypeId":2}]`.

Comment: Now the [votes on answers are shown correctly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2NO.png). It seems like the answers were swapped, but the vote buttons were not.

Comment: Most people don't report themselves for exploiting! It's good that the integrity of our user base is high! :D